# Wheel file installation

Tags: python, installation, python-wheel

How do I install a .whl file?

I have the wheel library, but I don't know how to use it to install those files.  I have the .whl file, but I don't know how to run it.

Answer (score 249, accepted):

You normally use a tool like `pip` to install wheels. Leave it to the tool to discover and download the file if this is for a project hosted on PyPI.

For this to work, you do need to install the `wheel` package:

```
pip install wheel
```

You can then tell `pip` to install the project (and it'll download the wheel if available), or the wheel file directly:

```
pip install project_name  # discover, download and install
pip install wheel_file.whl  # directly install the wheel
```

Also see the [`wheel` project documentation](http://wheel.rtfd.org/).

Comment: @bers: the `install` command was removed in 2018, see the changelog. This answer was last updated in 2015, I've removed that sentence now.

Answer (score 45):

If you already have a wheel file (.whl) on your PC, then just go with the following code:

```
cd ../user
pip install file.whl
```

If you want to download a file from web, and then install it, go with the following in command line:

```
pip install package_name
```

Or, if you have the URL:

```
pip install http//websiteurl.com/filename.whl
```

This will for sure install the required file.

Note: I had to type pip2 instead of pip while using Python 2.

Answer (score 8):

You can follow the below command to install using the wheel file at your local system:

```
pip install /users/arpansaini/Downloads/h5py-3.0.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use this command to make sure that you have the latest version and install a wheel:

```
venv/scripts/python -m pip install -U wheel package_name
```