# pip not installing modules

Tags: python, numpy, pip

As per object. I'm running Python 2.7.10 under Windows 7 64 bit. I added C:\Python27\Scripts to my PATH, and I can run `pip`, but it's not able to install modules. For example

```
pip install numpy
```

gives

```
Collecting numpy
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after
connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(11004,'getaddrinfo failed'))': /simple/numpy/
```

It keeps retrying and failing for a while, and then it exits with

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions:
)
No matching distribution found for numpy
```

Probably I'm behind a firewall, but I'm quite disappointed because I can install packages under [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) perfectly fine with `install.packages`, and I don't see why I can't do the same with Python. If I install packages manually (in the case of NumPy, from here

[NumPy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy/1.10.1)

what do I miss, with respect to using `pip`?

As per suggestions in the comments, I downloaded the .whl file for NumPy from [NumPy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy/1.10.1). I navigated to the downloads dir and executed

```
pip install numpy-1.10.1-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
```

I only got

```
numpy-1.10.1-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

What should I do?

Comment: there is no difference between packages you install with `pip` directly or by common procedure (downoald and install from pypi or other sources)

Comment: Anyway, module/packages with C-extension such as numpy needs C compilation during pip install which is not trivial especially on Windows. I would highly recommend downloading binary distribution from official site or C. Gohlke's site. On Windows, pip works only when modules are pure python or pypi has wheel package unless you have proper build system.

Comment: @otterb I'm 100% in favor of using binaries whenever possible, but how do I do that? from the page I link in my question, I clicked [this link](https://pypi.python.org/packages/cp27/n/numpy/numpy-1.10.1-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl#md5=b582a9de1e411a20555c04b852d1f6d1) and got a `whl` file. No Windows installer. So how do I install it?

Comment: I also tried `sourceforge`, precisely [this link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/latest/download?source=typ_redirect), and this time I got a `zip` file containing various folders with `py` files, but again I don't know what to do with them.

Comment: you can use pip to install whl file that you got. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002897/wheel-file-installation `pip install wheel_file.whl`

Comment: thanks! apologies for the trivial question, but don't I need to tell `pip` about the directory where I downloaded the file? Like `pip install C:\Downloads\wheel_file.whl`.

Comment: I navigated to the download directory and executed `pip install numpy-1.10.1-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl`. I only got `numpy-1.10.1-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.ma
cosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`. What is happening?

Comment: The clue is in the filename - that wheel is designed for OSX rather than Windows. Try one of the Windows binaries from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy), or install the [Anaconda Python distribution](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) instead.

Comment: If someone has come to this page due to failing docker image builds which contain pip modules' installation from requirements file as a build step: 

Solution : Add `--dns 8.8.8.8` as parameters to `/etc/sysconfig/docker` and restart docker daemon and try `docker build` again

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A proxy shall be used. For example:

```
python.exe -m pip install numpy --proxy="proxy.com:8080"
```

where "proxy.com:8080" is the proxy server address and port. This can be found in OS settings.

How to get them:

1. Windows: [What Is a Proxy or Proxy Server](https://www.whatismyip.com/what-is-a-proxy/)
2. Linux [How can I find out the proxy address I am behind?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276811/how-can-i-find-out-the-proxy-address-i-am-behind/276813)
3. Mac OS X: [How can I get Mac OS X's proxy information in a Bash script?](https://superuser.com/questions/48480/how-can-i-get-mac-os-xs-proxy-information-in-a-bash-script)

Comment: In --proxy="proxy.com:8080", what do I have to type instead of proxy.com?

Comment: I had extended my answer.

Comment: But what was the origin of the problem and why does using a proxy solve it?

Comment: The root problem was that executing: pip install numpy ends with error.

Comment: Can we define a proxy instead of define it every install?

Comment: Yes. By defining HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables.

Comment: This answer solved my issue. However, I strongly discourage you to set the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables. The reason is that the change will have an effect on the whole system and you don't want that probably.

Answer (score 2):

To bypass the firewall, you can use a proxy

```
pip install numpy --proxy <domain\user:password@proxyaddress:port>
```

For example,

```
pip install numpy --proxy http://<username>:<password>@proxy.xyz.com:2180
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it lacks explanation. Please consider adding text to explain what it does, and why it answers the question posed.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Anaconda:

I was trying to install Django using cmd, and it just was not working! I opened up the Anaconda prompt and ran the usual

```
py -m pip install Django
```

command, and hey presto! Django was installed!

Comment: installing anaconda is the only solution that worked for me after hours googling

Answer (score 0):

Personally, it was the configuration file in `~/.config/pip/pip.conf`, which contained an `extra-index-url`, preventing the download, because it made `pip` search for all the packages on this extra url instead of the main pip repository.

I experimented with old pip 8, because upgrading was even worse for this `extra-index-url` needed for another project.

Comment: What do you mean by *"blocking"*? In what way? Why and how does it block? Perhaps [elaborate](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65684217/edit) a little bit in your answer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one as well! Setting pip configuration using a proxy so that you do not need to concern the proxy issue again when you install packages via pip.

`pip config set global.proxy http://restrictedproxy.xxx.com:70`

```
http://restrictedproxy.xxx.com 
:70
```

you could probably ask the proxy domain  and the port from IT if you work for a company.

Answer (score 0):

Our company laptops were too locked down (with scripts and pac files in proxy settings, i.e. blackspider settings), and only the following worked for me.

To solve, I used the following simple steps:

- Go directly to [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/).
- Search for the library: **python-dateutil**
- Download it
- (Optional) Switch to the correct conda environment
- Install:

```
pip install "C:\Users\joe\Downloads\python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl"
```