# Python 3 on Anaconda - Cant install packages using pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip, anaconda

I installed the anaconda distribution in a new computer (windows 10 64 bit) and I cant install python packages via the anaconda prompt.

I have re-installed anaconda and updated everyhting - aconda navigator, pip, pip3 etc. And I have tried at least 10 possible solutions online but none seems to work.

I get the following error:

```
(base) C:\Windows\system32>pip install Scrapy
Collecting Scrapy
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/scrapy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/scrapy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/scrapy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/scrapy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/scrapy/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Scrapy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Scrapy

(base) C:\Windows\system32>pip3 install tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/tensorflow/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/tensorflow/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/tensorflow/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/tensorflow/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/tensorflow/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

For every package I try to install.

Python version: `Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jun 28 2018, 11:27:44) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

```
(base) C:\Windows\system32>conda list anaconda$
# packages in environment at C:\Users\vinic\Anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
anaconda                  custom           py36h363777c_0
```

**Edit:** If I use `conda install <package>` it seems to work, is there any difference?

I am trying to fix this for like 3 hours now and no success. Does anyone knows what could be going on?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably the firewall disabling pip. Conda and pip are different package managers so there is a difference. You might possibly have more than one python as well.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996026/pip-not-installing-modules) is a very similar problem to yours.

Try using proxy as the best answer in the linked question suggests. Disabling the firewall or allowing pip should work too.

Comment: I deactivated the firewall and I get the same error, I will try the proxy thing then