# python pip install seems to have an internet access source problem

Tags: python, pip

I'm using Python 3.7.2 on my machine with internet access. The installation of any package gives me the following problem:

```
M:>\pip install matplotlib 

Collecting matplotlib   Retrying
 (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by
 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection
 object at 0x04127270>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno
 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/matplotlib/   Retrying
 (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by
 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection
 object at 0x04127AD0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno
 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/matplotlib/   Retrying
 (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by
 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection
 object at 0x04127AB0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno
 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/matplotlib/   Retrying
 (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by
 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection
 object at 0x0414B390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno
 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/matplotlib/   Retrying
 (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by
 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection
 object at 0x0414B210>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno
 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/matplotlib/   Could not find a
 version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib (from versions: ) No
 matching distribution found for matplotlib
```

A.)  How can this be fixed?

A.1) It seems that some institution blocks a particular access. How can I switch the download URLs?

A.2) Are there some alternative mirrors and how can I accees them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please copy the output in a code block, not a quote block. This blob of text is unreadable to most humans.

Comment: Also, please verify that you can do `ping pypi.python.org`. My bet is you won't be able to.

Comment: Could you try using a VPN?

Comment: looks like I have to add my proxy: How can I do this?

Comment: Are you able to ping pypi.?

Comment: no ping from console possible. Browsers work correctly

Comment: can you download the `whl` file from pypi for matplotlib.? If then install using that like `pip install C:/some-dir/some-file.whl`

Comment: Install by setting the proxy E.g pip --proxy http://username:passsword@networkproxy:port install <packagename>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip not installing modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996026/pip-not-installing-modules)

Answer (score 1):

add nameserver 8.8.8.8 to the /etc/resolv.conf file.