# Error "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for flask"

Tags: python, pip

An exception occurs while installing a package using pip. I tried installing [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy), [Flask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flask_%28web_framework%29) and others, but I am getting the below error.

```
pip install flask

Collecting flask
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0667CB50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0667C190>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0667C7F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0667C8F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0667C0F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/flask/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for flask
```

How can I resolve it?

The pip version is 18.1, and the Python version is 3.7.

Comment: you may have a proxy issue. Are you on corp net? - That's usually the case

Comment: yes i am on corp net. how can i resolve proxy issues?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip not installing modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996026/pip-not-installing-modules)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, this is a hack that I always follow, but it works every time - I need to because my corporate network is behind heavy layered security.

Every time you need to install pip packages, run the following commands beforehand from your cmd (you don't need to be administrator):

```
set http_proxy=http://your_corp_username:password@<your_corp_proxy_host>:<port>
set https_proxy=https://your_corp_username:password@<your_corp_proxy_host>:<port>
```

Then run your usual pip commands.

If pip throws some SSL trust/resolution error, you can also do the following to trust pip by your network:

```
pip --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org install <some_package>
```

Use the following for installing packages under the current user only (this doesn't require administrator privileges)

```
pip --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org install <some_package>  --user
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This helps. i am able to install packages now.

Comment: @Rubens_Zimbres: answer helped for me.

Answer (score 4):

Your "f" should be "F":

```
pip install Flask
```

Comment: On my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with apt-get python installation I can use both flask/Flask.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that for current release [v1.0.2](https://pypi.org/project/Flask/) Python 3.7 [is not supported yet](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/dfd3619d6f8796d48fc4e32f819cec9e8aa59156/setup.py#L70). Its support does exist in the [master branch](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/setup.py#L72), but not yet released.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your internet connection if all above doesn't work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked out for me just installing python version 3.6.4 64-bit resolved the issue.

you can download from the below link:
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-364/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got a similar error and it ended up just being a typo: I tried to install `flask_coors` when it should have actually been `flask_cors`.