# Unable to install flask using python3.7 and pip3.7

Tags: python-3.x, pip, rhel7

I am trying to install flask using python pip in my linux machine having rhel7

```
-> python3.7 --version
Python 3.7.2
-> pip3.7 --version
pip 18.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Problem :

-> pip3.7 install flask

```
Collecting flask
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fad3a9f60b8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fad3a9f6128>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fad3a9f6390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fad3a9f6358>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/flask/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fad3a9f64e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable')': /simple/flask/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for flask
```

I tried to use below command as well but same error

```
python3.7 -m pip install flask
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55021270/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-flask-from-versions)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you look at this [Flask documentation page](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/installation/). As mention in the documentation, you need to [activate the environment](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/installation/#activate-the-environment) and then proceed to install by running the command [`pip install Flask`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/installation/#install-flask).

This doc also refers to Python 2.7 as well. Keep that in mind when following this doc.

Comment: Take a look at this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55021270/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-flask-from-versions

Comment: sudo /usr/local/bin/python3.7 -m pip install flask --proxy="host:port"

Comment: That's great! Don't forget to upvote that post to give credit to the person who answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

`pip3 install flask`

Or:

`pip install flask`

Good luck.