# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask (from versions: none)

Tags: python, flask

need a help with downloading Flask. I searched a lot of information about it, but unfortunately haven't found the right algorithm how to make it. 
here is the code

```
pip install -U Flask
```

Collecting Flask

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))': /simple/flask/

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for Flask

Using Mac OS 10.15.4, Python 3.8.3, have no proxy that's why this answer didn't help me [Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55021270/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-flask-from-versions)

P.S. Sorry if i made some mistakes in my english.

Comment: Have you tried pip3 install flask?

Comment: yep, the same error (

Comment: Could you try this please? `pip install -U https://github.com/pallets/flask/archive/master.tar.gz`

Comment: ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pallets/flask/archive/master.tar.gz (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error')))