# Issues installing packages with pip3 and python (ReadTimeoutError / SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError)

Tags: ssl, pip, package, flask-sqlalchemy, homebrew

I'm trying since a while now to install : *flask-sqlalchemy* and *pyscopg2* because I bought an online course on Fullstack Development.

**My settings are:**

- MacOs Mojave version 10.14.6
- Python -> Version = Python Python 3.7.7
- Postgres installed -> version = postgres (PostgreSQL) 12.3

**Error I get with : pip3 install flask-sqlalchemy  or pip3 install pyscopg2 :**

*WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pyscopg2/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyscopg2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyscopg2*

and

*WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/flask-sqlalchemy/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask-sqlalchemy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for flask-sqlalchemy*

So following : https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/issues/3826 I tried:

`pip3 install --default-timeout=1000 flask-sqlalchemy`

Then I get :

*WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/flask-sqlalchemy/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/flask-sqlalchemy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/flask-sqlalchemy/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1076)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask-sqlalchemy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for flask-sqlalchemy*

So I checked the following in Python3:

```
import ssl 

ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION

'OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020'

ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2

 <_SSLMethod.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2: 5>
```

**Other potential solutions I tried and which unfortunately didn't work :**

- `brew uninstall openssl; brew install openssl`
- *uninstall and reinstall python3*
- `pip3 install certifi`  according to https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4205
- `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo -H python3` according to [pip issue installing almost any library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370583/pip-issue-installing-almost-any-library/49798838)
- `pip3 --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org install flask-sqlalchemy  --user` didn't work, and I read afterwards this isn't very secure to bypass like this...

**So I really don't know what I should do, and installing packages with pip3 is supposed to be easy :) :**
- Please if someone could help, I don't know what I have to do more...

- Maybe linked [Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55021270/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-flask-from-versions)
  they say to

```
set http_proxy=http://your_corp_username:password@<your_corp_proxy_host>:<port>
set https_proxy=https://your_corp_username:password@<your_corp_proxy_host>:<port>
```

But :

- 1. I'm a bit afraid to mess with my actual settings
- 2. Not sure what's : *your_corp_username*
- 3. Not sure what's :
- 4. Not sure which port I should use for :  (as this is still new to me :( )

MANY  THANKS