# install pandas issue what to do?

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to install pandas today but I get this error report:

```
Collecting pandas
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pandas/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pandas/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pandas/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pandas/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))': /simple/pandas/
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pandas
```

In the command prompt I am typing `pip install pandas`.

How do I fix it?

Comment: try using `pip3 install pandas`

Comment: whats your python version?

Comment: is this an issue with your firewall? you can set the proxy `pip install pandas --proxy="proxy.com:8080"` where "proxy.com:8080" is the proxy server address and port. This can be found in OS settings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip not installing modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996026/pip-not-installing-modules)

Answer (score 0):

are you mixing conda and pip package managers? This is proving buggy, especially for closely linked packages, i.e. pandas/numpy/scipy

[image: demonstration]

The pandas version required by existing packages likely breaks something else. Try using an environment manager like conda or pipenv. Alternatively, check which version of NumPy is installed, and force an older one alongside pandas as shown above

Answer (score 0):

I get that error on my work laptop because i am connected through a proxy that does not let pip install from internet work. It seems that your issue is internet related as well. An easy fix would be to go to https://pypi.org/project/pandas/, download the file that works for your system and then pip install [filename]. Please note that you probably should not change the original filename from pypi.