# Update a package by easy_install

Tags: python, ubuntu, easy-install

I'm new to python. I would like to install the latest version of mitmproxy(0.17.1). The current version installed on the system is 0.15. When I do

```
easy_install -U mitmproxy
```

It says:

```
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/mitmproxy/
Best match: mitmproxy 0.15
Processing mitmproxy-0.15-py2.7.egg
mitmproxy 0.15 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
```

So it can not find the latest version and when I do:

```
easy_install  'mitmproxy==0.17.1'
```

I get :

```
No local packages or download links found for mitmproxy==0.17.1
```

Why can't it find the latest version? What should I do to install the latest one?

Answer (score 1):

From [Why use pip over easy_install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install) (bold mine):

> Binary packages are now distributed as wheels (.whl files)—not just on PyPI, but in third-party repositories like Christoph Gohlke's Extension Packages for Windows. **`pip` can handle wheels; `easy_install` cannot.**

If you visit the [mitmproxy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mitmproxy) page on PyPi, you will notice that the only download there for version `0.17` is in `.whl` format.

That is why `easy_install` does not work for you: it can't find anything that it actually *can* install for the latest version.

### Solution

- [Install and use `pip` instead like everyone else.](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/02/how-install-pip-ubuntu/) .
- If for some reason you cannot use `pip`, follow instructions here: [Wheel file installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002897/wheel-file-installation)

  - Essentially, install `wheel` from the TAR archive [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel#downloads).
  - Manually download the `.whl` file you'd like to install.
  - Run from the command line.

    ```
    python -m wheel install mitmproxy-0.17-py2-none-any.whl
    ```