# 'SSLError' installing with pip

Tags: python, django, windows, ssl

I'm trying to install Django on a Windows 10 system.

Whatever I try to install with pip on cmd, I get these errors:

```
Collecting django
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/django/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/django/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/django/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1056)'))) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for django
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1056)'))) - skipping
```

I've tried a lot of things from other questions but none is working.

```
pip install --upgrade pip --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org

pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org django
```

Comment: your firewall is not allowing pip to connect to internet, so allow pip from the windows firewall and it will work

Comment: make sure that you have strong internet connection and allow firewall to connect to pip **refer this** https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6152

Comment: @Exprator The internet connection isn't a problem so it's probably the company's firewall and I don't think I can allow it myself. Is there another way to install django?

Comment: Doing a trace route might shed some light on where it is being block. From `cmd`, try `tracert pypi.python.org`. If you see an address with `*` displayed, that means it can't reach that hop point.

Comment: @FlipperPA I have indeed * displayed so I guess it can't reach ....This is probably because of the company's firewall and I tried some commands with proxy but nothing seems to works

Comment: If you're using a VPN, it may be best to disable it first. This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I asked a colleague who automatically knew what to do. I just had to set the proxy variables:

```
set https_proxy=http://username:password@proxy.example.com:8080
set http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy.example.com:8080
```

and it works.

Comment: Setting in what context? In some batch file? Directly on the command line before some install steps? Something else? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56649266/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 57):

Setting up my proxy correctly fixed this for me as well. The problem was that I used the http**s** protocol for my HTTPS_PROXY and https_proxy environment variables.

Use:

```
HTTPS_PROXY="http://username:password@proxy.example.com:8080"
https_proxy="http://username:password@proxy.example.com:8080"
```

Do **not** use:

```
HTTPS_PROXY="https://username:password@proxy.example.com:8080"
https_proxy="https://username:password@proxy.example.com:8080"
```

Comment: Working! Next time developers had not idea how things works...

Comment: WOW. It really worked - use http instead of https for HTTPS_PROXY

Comment: Working. Just also created an environmental variable with the proxy I am using. No need to not upgrade to pip to 20.3.1.

Comment: After 7 years ..still holds good ..Python 3.9.4

Comment: just in case someone gets here, in powershell, this worked for me:
```$env:HTTPS_PROXY = "http://proxy:port"
$env:https_proxy = "http://proxy:port"```

Comment: This works, but does it have any security implications if https traffic uses a http proxy?

Comment: In what file does it go?

Comment: In the file you define your environment variables. It's OS and shell dependent

Answer (score 12):

My pip was working fine (Windows 7 and Python 3.8.6) until I upgraded pip from version 20.2.1 to 20.3.1, after which I also got the error:

> SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER error.

This is reproducible. I uninstalled and reinstalled several times to confirm.

**Solution (well, workaround)**: don't upgrade pip to 20.3.1.

*Note*: pip 20.3.1 works fine in my Windows 7/Python 3.9.1 environment.

Comment: Probably the only valid answer!

Comment: I found by trial and error that 20.2.4 was the highest version that works for me with python 3.7.9

Comment: I also ran into this issue with a fresh install of Python 3.9.1 on Win10 and upgrade to pip 21.0.1. Solution was to reinstall Python and stay with pip on version 20.2.3. We have a SSL Interception Proxy and i tried to set global.cert which seems not to be used by pip 21.0.1. I filed an issue: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9614

Comment: @LuciusSilanus How you solve your problem, may you share ?

Comment: @UğurGürkanTosun I had to download a wheel for pip 20.2.4 and install it from the wheel file (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28002930/4871972)

Comment: but how can I install an older version of pip without pip

Answer (score 4):

Check your proxy setting. You can use this command

```
pip install <package> --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --proxy="<IP>:<port>"
```

Comment: I still have this error :  " Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0378E390>, 'Connection to 192.168.0.254 timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/django/"

Comment: This command works fine `pip install <package> --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --proxy="http://<username>:<password>@<IP>:<port>"`

Comment: Worked for me as well. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the system proxy. The `trusted-host` flag, to my knowledge, is used when pip wants to query an insecure `http` index and pip defaults to query only SSL secured indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Try finding and removing [OpenSSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL) (OS level installation), if it's installed on your system.

In my case, I installed OpenSSL on Windows 10 (for some other development tasks) long time ago and forgot about it, which was the main culprit. I uninstalled it, and it solved the issue.