# Error using pip (SSL WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER ) after updating it

Tags: python, pip

I was installing some Python packages (like Numpy) directly from the prompt using pip (I use a Windows machine). Then I updated the pip from 19.0.3 to 21.0.1.

Now when I try to install a package using pip I get the following message:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/py-trees/ 
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/py-trees/ 
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/py-trees/ 
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/py-trees/ 
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/py-trees/
    
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/py-trees/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/py-trees/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement py_trees
ERROR: No matching distribution found for py_trees Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)'))) - skipping
```

Why is this happening now? Do anyone now how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSLError installing with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56628194/sslerror-installing-with-pip)