# Why requests raise this exception "check_hostname requires server_hostname"?

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

```
p={
    'http':'http://my correct proxy here',
    'https':'https://my correct proxy here'
    }
self.response=requests.get(url=url,headers=self.headers,timeout=(6,15),proxies=p)
```

And then it raise the exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xyl13509876955\Desktop\Monitor\dicks.py", line 61, in send_request
    self.response=requests.get(url=url,headers=self.headers,timeout=(6,15),proxies=p)
  File "C:\Users\xyl13509876955\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xyl13509876955\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xyl13509876955\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xyl13509876955\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xyl13509876955\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\xyl13509876955\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 696, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "C:\Users\xyl13509876955\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 964, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\xyl13509876955\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 359, in connect
    conn = self._connect_tls_proxy(hostname, conn)
  File "C:\Users\xyl13509876955\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 506, in _connect_tls_proxy
    ssl_context=ssl_context,
  File "C:\Users\xyl13509876955\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 432, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls)
  File "C:\Users\xyl13509876955\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 474, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "C:\Users\xyl13509876955\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 423, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "C:\Users\xyl13509876955\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 827, in _create
    raise ValueError("check_hostname requires server_hostname")
ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname
```

Please help me solve the problem and the best way is to show me the right code. I am very confused and frustrated for the problem!!

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Comment: I get the error just from running `pip3 install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As I understand, in new urllib3 the main schema of proxy was changed... can read [here](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/2075).
This settings help for me (for urllib3=1.26.4).

An old

```
proxy={
    'http':'8.88.888.8:8888',
    'https':'8.88.888.8:8888'
    }
```

The new

```
proxy={
    'https': 'https://8.88.888.8:8888',
    'http': 'http://8.88.888.8:8888',
    }
```

---

UPDATED

I have met this issue again for **requests 2.26.0**, but in this time it works with an old schema...

```
proxy={
    'http':'8.88.888.8:8888',
    'https':'8.88.888.8:8888'
    }
```

---

Comment: This is might be important to some:
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/10590

Answer (score 40):

as a work around:

> pip install urllib3==1.25.11

Comment: @scrubjay55 This actually worked! I spent one day and had almost given up on the SSL error. Tried a lot of solutions but nothing worked.. Relieved finally :) Thank you!

How did you find out the fix?

Comment: Same error when executing "pip install urllib3==1.25.11" ...

Comment: this worked for me. But I'm keen to properly fix this issue soon.

Comment: I had to disable the proxy in Windows settings to be able to downgrade urllib3. Afterwards the issue is gone even with active proxy settings.

Answer (score 22):

I have solved the problem. It is a bug with urllib3.

You can use `pip install urllib3==1.25.8`

Comment: can confirm this worked with python 2.7  and very useful to put in requirements.txt to ensure the version is precise

Comment: This solved my problem with python 3.9.6 requests module using proxies, thanks KEVIN

Comment: This solved my problem with python3.10.10 running on MacOS 13.0.1 as well. How on earth has this been a problem for over two years without being fixed?

Answer (score 7):

Downgrading urllib3 has solved it for me too.
Though I had to reset the proxy env var:
`https_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:<PROXY_PORT>" pip install urllib3==1.25.11`

Without that, I was getting the following error and it couldn't downgrade urllib3 (see [SSLError installing with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56628194/sslerror-installing-with-pip)).

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1091)'))': /simple/pip/
```

Comment: mee too. What's the value of PROXY_PORT?

Comment: Depends on your proxy server. It should be your proxy address (not necessarily 127.0.0.1 as in my case) and the port.

Comment: In my case, changing the value of the https_proxy variable from https to http solved the issue by itself.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04 using Python 3.6.9, searched through a lot of pages and finally fixed it via trial and error.

The fix is changing the environment variable `https_proxy`. Previously `https_proxy` is `https://127.0.0.1:<PORT>` and I removed the `https` header via:

`export https_proxy=127.0.0.1:<PORT>`

Then I can do `python3 -m pip install --upgrade urllib3`.

Comment: Thanks, this works in windows too, set HTTPS_PROXY=127.0.0.1:3128, then it worked

Answer (score 5):

In my case, [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/)' `windows proxy` function caused this error. After I close `windows proxy`, this error is gone.

Comment: Similar situation, I turned down my "System Proxy" and the problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

**None of the answers did it for me. Here's a silly looking solution that fixed my problem:**

If you, like me trying to install packages in a corporate environment, you probably have given a proxy to limit interactions with world wide web, so all you have to do is to export that proxy in http and https format.

something like this:

```
export http_proxy=http://x.x.x.x:8080

export https_proxy=http://x.x.x.x:8080
```

(my proxy didnt use the ssl, it didnt even matter.)

replace x with your proxy ip

Comment: worked for me thanks a lot man ;)

Answer (score 3):

Turn Your VPN/Proxy thing (which enables as System Proxy) maybe it fixed.

i was using QV2ray and i had this issue, when i disabled it, pip works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use VPN proxy service off it and try again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This has already been mentioned in other answers. *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*

Comment: This is the right answer!!!

Comment: Yes but I did not vote

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, the problem can be resolved by replacing `https` with `http` in the proxy settings environment variable `export https_proxy=http://123.123.123.123:8888`. Note, it is proxy settings for `https`, but an `http` address is used.

Comment: Work for me! But can you explain why?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue, the proxy config is enabled by accident. Just turning off the proxy worked for me.

Comment: I had to turn of the proxy (in Windows settings) to be able to install `urllib3==1.25.11` as suggested in other answers. Otherwise the installation of old urllib3 using pip failed with the same error message. After the installation of old urllib3, the issue is gone even with active proxy settings.

Answer (score 2):

As others mention, it has something to do with the connection to the server.

I solved it simply by closing Fiddler.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I was using a proxy. I disabled the proxy, the error was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you that *can't* disable their proxy, I found that downgrading pip was the only thing that worked.
The version that works for me is located here:
[https://pypi.org/project/pip/20.2.4/](https://%20https://pypi.org/project/pip/20.2.4/)

Download the whl and use

```
pip install pip-20.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

at the location you downloaded it to.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Python 3.10.7 (64-bit) on Windows 10.

Rolling back urllib3 to 1.25.11 didn't help.

Using python 3.19.13 (64-bit) instead resolved this error message no matter
which urllib3 is used.

I assume that this is caused by some compatibility issue with Python 3.10.x.