# Why i am not able to install python module through PIP

Tags: pip, python-3.6, urllib3

I am trying to install python modules, but i am getting ERROR.

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 773, in __init__
    raise ValueError("check_hostname requires server_hostname")
ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname
```

On search the error, i came across a  stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66642705/why-requests-raise-this-exception-check-hostname-requires-server-hostname)

As per the post, thereis a bug in urllib3, so there are some work around that is suggested there. But it is not working either.  On further research, I saw  a [GIT-HUB](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2435) link that is talking about the error.

It has given the difference between the working machine and a broken machine. My machine has below output as per the suggestions.

```
print("OS", platform.platform())
OS Linux-4.15.0-143-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic

>>> print("Python", platform.python_version())
Python 3.6.9

>>> print("urllib3", urllib3.__version__)
urllib3 1.22
```

But I didn't find any solution for this. Please suggest how to fix this error.

I am trying to install below:

```
sudo pip install python-dev
```

But its happening with every module.

I have already uninstalled and installed PIP for 3. But no help.

Please suggest. Thank you.