# error in creating python environment in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I download anaconda as the Internet said, and use command 'conda create -n python python=3.6' and it shows "Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json):failed" and the error report says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\exceptions.py", line 72, in exception_handler
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 146, in start_app
    window = run_app(splash)
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 65, in run_app
    window = MainWindow(splash=splash)
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\main_window.py", line 165, in __init__
    self.api = AnacondaAPI()
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\anaconda_api.py", line 1518, in AnacondaAPI
    ANACONDA_API = _AnacondaAPI()
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\anaconda_api.py", line 83, in __init__
    self._client_api = ClientAPI(config=self.config)
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\client_api.py", line 659, in ClientAPI
    CLIENT_API = _ClientAPI(config=config)
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\client_api.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.reload_client()
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\client_api.py", line 326, in reload_client
    client.user()
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binstar_client\__init__.py", line 244, in user
    res = self.session.get(url, verify=self.session.verify)
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 696, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 964, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 359, in connect
    conn = self._connect_tls_proxy(hostname, conn)
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 500, in _connect_tls_proxy
    return ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 432, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls)
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 474, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 997, in _create
    raise ValueError("check_hostname requires server_hostname")
ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname
```

I search this on the Internet for a long time but get no answer. I use windows 10. Hope someone can help me!

Comment: man, how did you searched the internet for a long time? I am seeing the very exact issue already answered over SO , hope below links may help! 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66642705/why-requests-raise-this-exception-check-hostname-requires-server-hostname 

https://exerror.com/valueerror-check_hostname-requires-server_hostname/

Comment: _I download anaconda as the Internet said_ Can you be more specific? Also, I would recommend using a different name for the environment, calling it _python_ will just be confusing.