# ERROR: while installing Ipex using docker centos image

Tags: intel-pytorch

Unable to install Ipex using docker centos image

I pulled this docker image: docker pull sysstacks/dlrs-pytorch-centos

Tried to run on my linux machine with this command: docker run -it sysstacks/dlrs-pytorch-centos bash

I was trying to install Ipex using centos docker image (image name: sysstacks/dlrs-pytorch-centos) unfortunately i got this error.

[after setting env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPkpb.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIniu.png)

```html
[root@0d96884d3a05 /]# python -m pip install torch_ipex==1.9.0 -f https://software.intel.com/ipex-whl-stable
Looking in links: https://software.intel.com/ipex-whl-stable
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 180, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 204, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 319, in run
    reqs, check_supported_wheels=not options.target_dir
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 128, in resolve
    requirements, max_rounds=try_to_avoid_resolution_too_deep
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 473, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 341, in resolve
    name, crit = self._merge_into_criterion(r, parent=None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 172, in _merge_into_criterion
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/structs.py", line 139, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 143, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 129, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 30, in _iter_built
    for version, func in infos:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 272, in iter_index_candidate_infos
    hashes=hashes,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 879, in find_best_candidate
    candidates = self.find_all_candidates(project_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 824, in find_all_candidates
    page_candidates = list(page_candidates_it)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/sources.py", line 134, in page_candidates
    yield from self._candidates_from_page(self._link)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 783, in process_project_url
    html_page = self._link_collector.fetch_page(project_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 512, in fetch_page
    return _get_html_page(location, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 422, in _get_html_page
    resp = _get_html_response(url, session=session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 137, in _get_html_response
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 449, in request
    return super().request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 53, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 696, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 964, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connection.py", line 359, in connect
    conn = self._connect_tls_proxy(hostname, conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connection.py", line 506, in _connect_tls_proxy
    ssl_context=ssl_context,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 432, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 474, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 365, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 732, in __init__
    raise ValueError("check_hostname requires server_hostname")
```

NOTE:
I have tried all these methods shown below but none of them worked
[Why requests raise this exception "check_hostname requires server_hostname"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66642705/why-requests-raise-this-exception-check-hostname-requires-server-hostname)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is with your proxy, can you please try below commands in your docker container:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://x.x.x.x
    
export https_proxy=http://x.x.x.x
    
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://x.x.x.x
    
export http_proxy=http://x.x.x.x
```

Change `x` with your proxy ip