# Error installing with Pip, can't downgrade pip

Tags: python, ssl, pip

When I try to install a package with pip, I get the error:

`WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /simple/matplotlib`

This is the same as the error reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56628194/sslerror-installing-with-pip). The problem is that I'm stuck in something of a catch 22: the recommended answer at the linked problem is to downgrade pip to 20.2.4. Only problem is; I can't work out a simple way to do this because I can't use pip to install the previous version of pip. I tried using 'easy_install' to do it, but it doesn't seem to be installed. I'm on python 3.9.5, on windows.

As you can probably tell, I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to this stuff.

Comment: You can always download the wheels from ``pypi.org`` and then do a local install, this should also work for pip, as long as you're using ``python -m pip ...``, because the pip binray does not like to be replaced while it's running. But then again this sounds like a XY problem to me, because I'm also on Win10, running python 3.9.5 and can install/update/delete packages via pip just fine. Maybe you should check out the other answers in the issue you've linked instead of focusing on downgrading pip.

Comment: Thanks - yeah there's something very confusing about my situation, because all the other people running into this problem seem to be operating behind a proxy of some sort, and I'm not. I've found it very hard to work out what is actually going on.

Comment: Ah! I've solved it! I was using the program 'Freedom' to help keep me on task - and that's a proxy server. I just uninstalled it and pip works fine!