# i am trying to install a pyhon module and its not working

Tags: python, module, python-wheel

my problem is very strange I have looked at problems others have had with installing modules but there answers do not seem to work for me. I use the command `pip install *file name.whl*`. But when I run the command it says invalid syntax and indicates to the word install. if anyone can help I would be very great full as I can not carry out my project with out this module

Comment: What exactly are you trying to install? And may I point you to a possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002897/wheel-file-installation

Comment: I am installing pynput

Comment: Try without the asterisks and without the .whl, `pip install pynput`

Comment: I have tried both methods and it just responds with syntax error and has an arrow pointing to install

Comment: `python -m pip install pynput`?

Comment: yep I tried that as well