# pip install + pip cant instelled the weel file from a local flat directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, rhel, python-wheel

we are trying to install the following wheel file

```
  ls /tmp/test
    argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

one option is:

```
pip install --no-index --find-links=file:///tmp/test argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
WARNING: Requirement 'argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
Looking in links: file:///tmp/test
Processing ./argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl'
```

the second option is:

```
pip install --no-index --find-links=/tmp/test argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
WARNING: Requirement 'argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
Looking in links: /tmp/test
Processing ./argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl'
```

***on both option pip failed to find the  `.whl` file***

what is interesting is that pip ignore the folder `/tmp/test`

what is going here ? , why pip cant installed the `wheel` file and find it under `/tmp/test` folder?

reference:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wheel file installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002897/wheel-file-installation)

Comment: Either **1.** you pass the full path to a _wheel_ file or **2.** you give `--no-index`, `--find-links` with the path to the directory containing the _wheel_, and the name of the project contained in the wheel (not the file name of the wheel).

Comment: just little question - 
can we use the option pip install --no-index --find-links=file:///tmp/test argparse --force-reinstall OR pip install --no-index --find-links=file:///tmp/test argparse --ignore-installed

Comment: Not entirely sure, so you should try for yourself. My assumption would be that if (case **1.**) you provide the full path to the wheel file explicitly, then it will be installed no matter what is already installed. But if (case **2.**) you provide the project name (`SomePackage`, or `argparse` with the index and links options), then you might have to provide the options `--ignore-installed` and/or `--force-reinstall` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that you need to use the package *name* rather than the wheel's file name. Try

```
pip install --no-index --find-links=file:///tmp/test/ argparse
```

However, [installing the wheel directly should work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file#comment46633660_27909082):

```
pip install /tmp/test/argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

Comment: why we cant to use this -  pip install --no-index --find-links=file:///tmp/test argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
 ? with full path of the file?

Comment: Because you are using --find_links which does something very specific. Try the second option that I gave.

Comment: how to check if - wheel library installed: ?

Comment: Please use Google for such questions. https://askubuntu.com/questions/588390/how-do-i-check-whether-a-module-is-installed-in-python-and-install-it-if-needed

Comment: can we use the option pip install --no-index --find-links=file:///tmp/test argparse --force-reinstall   OR pip install --no-index --find-links=file:///tmp/test argparse --ignore-installed

Comment: about the option- pip install /tmp/test/argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl , no so good because I want to work off line on local folder - we not have network internet ,