# Installing Python3.7 from source

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I need to use Python3.7, so I followed these instructions to install it

```
curPath=${pwd}
cd /usr/src
sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.9/Python-3.7.9.tgz
sudo tar xzf Python-3.7.9.tgz
cd Python-3.7.9
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
cd ${pwd}
```

I then tried to run `python -V` and got

```
Command 'python3.7' not found, did you mean:

  command 'python2.7' from deb python2.7 (2.7.18-1~20.04)
  command 'python3.9' from deb python3.9 (3.9.0-5~20.04)
  command 'python3.8' from deb python3.8 (3.8.5-1~20.04.2)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

Also I tried to run `whereis python` and got

```
whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3.8-config /usr/lib/python3.8 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.9 /etc/python3.8 /usr/local/lib/python3.8 /usr/include/python3.8
```

Comment: If it works on 18.04, why use 20.04. You can also use 18.04 on AWS?

Comment: @Marcin Actually I don't think it is working on Azure, the Azure Ubuntu just already had a  `python3.7` installed, when I try `whereis python3.7` on Azure, the one inside `/usr/src` doesn't show up

Comment: You ran configure. Did you run make?

Comment: @snapshoe is right.  Plus, "configure" and "make" don't need "sudo".  Only the tinal "make install" does.

Comment: Hi. How did it go with the issue?

Comment: @Marcin I figured it out, I had to download a bunch of stuff and can't quite remember what worked. I'll post an answer when I figure out what exactly worked, but it'll prob be sometime in the future

Comment: I see. So my answer did not work? The only dependencies needed for ubuntu 20.04 are `build-essential zlib1g-dev`.

Comment: @Marcin I don't think so

Comment: That's intresting. I verified it. Did you get any errors?

Comment: @Marcin I don't remember what happend exactly, I just remember being frustrated and trying a million things

Comment: Its best to try on fresh instance. If you already setup some wrong dependence, half-complied packaged, it is likely to fail. Anyway, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this script, I was able to install `python3.7` on ubuntu 18

```
curPath=${pwd}
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc
sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev libffi-dev wget liblzma-dev lzma
cd /usr/src
sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.9/Python-3.7.9.tgz
sudo tar xzf Python-3.7.9.tgz
cd Python-3.7.9
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make
sudo make altinstall
cd ${pwd}
```

---

But you should probably just install it with `pyenv`, here's a script that will install `pyenv` on linux, and then install python 3.7.9 . This method happens a lot faster, the first installation takes about an hour.

```
sudo apt-get install gcc build-essential libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev lzma

curl https://pyenv.run | bash

bashrc="${HOME}/.bashrc"
bash_profile="${HOME}/.bash_profile"
profile="${HOME}/.profile"

checkAndAppend () {
    # Checks if some text is in a file, and if it isn't, it appends that text at the end of the file
    # $1 - The text to insert into a file
    # $2 - A file to insert text into
    if ! grep -q $2 <<< "${1}" ; then 
        echo $1 >> $2
    fi 2>/dev/null
}

checkAndAppend 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' $profile
checkAndAppend 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' $profile
checkAndAppend 'eval "$(pyenv init --path)"' $profile
checkAndAppend 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' $bashrc
checkAndAppend 'eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"' $bashrc
checkAndAppend 'source $HOME/.profile' $bash_profile

RED='\033[0;31m'
printf $RED'
If your $HOME/.profile sources $HOME/.bashrc, then these lines must be inserted into $HOME/.profile before that

    export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
    export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
    eval "$(pyenv init --path)"

'

source $profile
source $bashrc
source $bash_profile

pyenv install 3.7.9
```

Answer (score 1):

I adapted your script to work as [UserData](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) script on Ubuntu 20.04 instance:

```
#!/bin/bash

apt update
apt install -y build-essential zlib1g-dev

curPath=${pwd}
cd /usr/src
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.9/Python-3.7.9.tgz
tar xzf Python-3.7.9.tgz
cd Python-3.7.9
#./configure --enable-optimizations
./configure 
make
make install
cd ${pwd}
```