# ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects on linux

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory

I install google colab on linux and this goes like this :

```
  INFO: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -g -fwrapv -O2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/pandas/_libs/index.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/pandas/_libs/tslibs/src/datetime/np_datetime.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/pandas/_libs/tslibs/src/datetime/np_datetime_strings.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/pandas/_libs/index.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  building 'pandas._libs.indexing' extension
  INFO: C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC
  
  INFO: compile options: '-Ipandas/_libs/src/klib -Ipandas/_libs/src -I/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c'
  extra options: '-Wno-unused-function'
  INFO: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: pandas/_libs/indexing.c
  pandas/_libs/indexing.c:217:12: fatal error: longintrepr.h: No such file or directory
    217 |   #include "longintrepr.h"
        |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: Command "x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -Ipandas/_libs/src/klib -Ipandas/_libs/src -I/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.11 -c pandas/_libs/indexing.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/pandas/_libs/indexing.o -Wno-unused-function" failed with exit status 1
  [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas
Running setup.py clean for pandas
Failed to build pandas
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

solutions i have tried upgrading my pip, upgrading my python, reinstalling again. nothing works
I need to use this code in my project:
from google.colab import files
I have have gone through these solutions also: [ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72401377/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-pandas-which-is-required-to-install-pyproject)
[Building wheel for pandas on Ubuntu 20.04 takes more than 20 minutes, but not on 18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62885419/building-wheel-for-pandas-on-ubuntu-20-04-takes-more-than-20-minutes-but-not-on)

Comment: Can you add more details to help reproduce this? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask