# pip fails to install. Results in "command errored out with exit status 1"

Tags: python, pip

thanks for the help with this question I appreciate you all. Pip will not install anything for me aside from generic boring python packages.  Is there a way to manually install packages without going through this insufferable process?

```
    pip3 install scrublet


Requirement already satisfied: scrublet in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\scrublet-0.2.1-py3.9.egg (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cython in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\cython-3.0a6-py3.9.egg (from scrublet) (3.0a6)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from scrublet) (1.20.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from scrublet) (1.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\scikit_learn-0.24.1-py3.9-win-amd64.egg (from scrublet) (0.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-image in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from scrublet) (0.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from scrublet) (3.3.4)
Collecting annoy
  Using cached annoy-1.17.0.tar.gz (646 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numba in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\numba-0.53.0rc2-py3.9-win-amd64.egg (from scrublet) (0.53.0rc2)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas-1.2.2-py3.9-win-amd64.egg (from scrublet) (1.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: umap-learn in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\umap_learn-0.5.1-py3.9.egg (from scrublet) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->scrublet) (8.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->scrublet) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->scrublet) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.3 in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->scrublet) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->scrublet) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib->scrublet) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: llvmlite<0.37,>=0.36.0rc1 in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from numba->scrublet) (0.36.0rc2)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from numba->scrublet) (54.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pandas->scrublet) (2021.1)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx>=2.0 in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from scikit-image->scrublet) (2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: tifffile>=2019.7.26 in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from scikit-image->scrublet) (2021.2.26)
Requirement already satisfied: imageio>=2.3.0 in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from scikit-image->scrublet) (2.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyWavelets>=1.1.1 in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from scikit-image->scrublet) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator>=4.3.0 in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from networkx>=2.0->scikit-image->scrublet) (4.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn->scrublet) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn->scrublet) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pynndescent>=0.5 in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from umap-learn->scrublet) (0.5.2)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for annoy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: annoy
    Running setup.py install for annoy ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-omk6ze2e\\annoy_3047d582a1534335aeb9b39626f0c183\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-omk6ze2e\\annoy_3047d582a1534335aeb9b39626f0c183\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Windows\Temp\pip-record-x7azmtt5\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\annoy'
         cwd: C:\Windows\Temp\pip-install-omk6ze2e\annoy_3047d582a1534335aeb9b39626f0c183\
    Complete output (11 lines):
    WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\annoy
    copying annoy\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\annoy
    running build_ext
    building 'annoy.annoylib' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-omk6ze2e\\annoy_3047d582a1534335aeb9b39626f0c183\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Windows\\Temp\\pip-install-omk6ze2e\\annoy_3047d582a1534335aeb9b39626f0c183\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Windows\Temp\pip-record-x7azmtt5\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\annoy' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Have you tried to follow the suggestion to get the cpp build tools? To answer your question, check [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002897/wheel-file-installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002897/wheel-file-installation) for manual package installation. PROTIP: "I work in R, which is MUCH better than python" is a good way to offend people.

Comment: I added an answer below, but the introduction where you praise R and trash Python is unnecessary and inappropriate.

Comment: @hlfrmn Wheel wouldn't help as `annoy` doesn't provide wheels.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+or+greater+is+required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the packages you are installing, I would recommend trying [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual). It will install all of your data science related packages for you and make sure there are NO version mismatches between packages.

In my experience, I've spend dozens of hours fighting with screens like the one above. Then, I used the Anaconda distribution and everything "just worked".

Comment: Thank you @SpaceKatt .  Coming back to python years later i found anaconda works well.