# Coverage module is not picking installed modules at run(third party modules installed via wheel files)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-wheel, coverage.py

I have installed a third party wheel file and I implemented/used one of the classes & exceptions(from wheel) into my piece of code. I wrote some unit-test cases for my piece of code. I am able to mock all the imports from wheel file apart from Exceptions.
When I tried I am seeing following error :

> TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is
> not allowed

Over Pycharm I overcome this scenario by installing wheel file and catching original exceptions instead of mocking them.

Whenever I tried to run the same class using coverage module (via terminal) I am seeing same exception again.

command I used to run this code:

> python3  -m  coverage  -m  unittest2  *.py

I am seeing the following error:

> TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is
> not allowed

Comment: Did you use `pip` to install your third party wheel file like mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28002930/15433312?

Comment: yes @Cheukting  I have installed third party wheel using pip. I am able to validate it using 
1. I am able to import classes & exceptions in python terminal.
2. I am able to validate using python -m <class name>

Comment: I ran each test python file individually then it worked. as shown below:      python3 -m coverage -m unittest2 test_class_1.py test_class_2.py test_class_3.py