# Issue while installing python package Spire.Doc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

i am using python version 3.10.0
command
`pip install Spire.Doc`

[image]

configuration

- python version 3.10.0
- pip 24.0 from
  /home/ubuntu/myen1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
- ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

installing package  [Spire.Doc](https://pypi.org/project/Spire.Doc/)

i want to try to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The docs shows how to install this package in VSCode. If you have VSCode, you can follow the steps on [How to Install Spire.Doc for Python in VS Code](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Python/Spire.Doc-for-Python/Getting-Started/How-to-Install-Spire.Doc-for-Python-in-VS-Code.html#:%7E:text=Getting%20Started-,How%20to%20Install%20Spire.Doc%20for%20Python%20in%20VS%20Code,-Spire.Doc%20for).

Alternatively, you can [download the wheel for your platform](https://pypi.org/project/Spire.Doc/#files) and then [install the .whl file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002897/wheel-file-installation). I'm guessing you need the wheel for Linux.

If your error persists, you should consider downgrading your Python version.